# Magento 1.9 - setting different prices for sizes of products in different stores?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

i want to set different prices for the sizes of my products in different stores. I have a configurable products which has a size-attribute. Now I want to set a price of 10 EUR for the "10x10"-option in Store 1 and 20 EUR for the "10x10"-option in Store 2. Now we tried the following module: http://bsscommerce.com/magento-multistore-pricing.html but it can only handle the base price of the confiugrable product and not the different attribute prices.

I am just wondering if we are the only ones which faced the same problem. I know that magento has only the website scope option buildin to differentiate the prices in the catalog but is this the correct solution?

Does someone has a similiar problem or can suggest another module? There is this other module: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-view-pricing.html but the rating is not that great and the credentials to login in their demo-backend are simply wrong so I can't check my problem in their demo.

Comment: You could create separate categories for each store. This would be a hassle if you have thousands of products and obviously it would be two different products from a store to another. There are many ways of automating this via import jobs. In our experience most of the time those extensions break after a Magento update and we spend sometimes days trying to solve it as most module providers will charge you for a fix or sometimes not even reply to your emails, so in the long run having an extension can be more expensive.